# Number of rank 1 matrices with $0/1$ entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

How many rank $1$ matrices in $\mathbb Z^{m\times n}$ are there if entries are restricted to $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Are the rank one factors restricted to being integers too?

Comment: rank 1 factor meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of only zeros and ones. The number of one/zero matrices for which row span is equal to $v$ is then $2^m-1$ because each row can be either $v$ or $0$ and it can't contain all zero vectors. Summing up over $2^n-1$ possible nonzero $v$ vectors we get the answer of:
$$(2^n-1)(2^m-1)$$

Comment: There is no way it can be $\leq\min(m,n)+\frac{\max(m,n)}2$ correct?

Comment: No, the equality $(2^n-1)(2^m-1) \le min(m,n)+max(m,n)/2$ is satisfied only for $(n,m)=(1,1), (2,1), (1,2)$ or $n=0$ or $m=0$.